# How do I reference the local variable when creating Url.Action call?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

Backstory:  To specify the correct route for a jqGrid that I show on my ASP.NET MVC 3 page, I do something like so:

```
$('#jqgFlavors').jqGrid({
   url: '@Url.Action("FlavorData", "IceCream")',
etc...
```

and that will produce the correct route either when running locally out of Visual Studio (where things live at something like `"http://localhost:90125/IceCream"`  or on the deployed site where things live at something like `"http://thehostsite/mydeployedsitename/IceCream"`.

Great.  Now the issue I'm having is that I use the `onSelectRow` in the grid to do a master/details thing based on the selected row's flavor id value.  First, I tried doing this to just get the route correct:

```
onSelectRow: function(theRow){
   $('#flavorDetails').load('@Url.Action("Details","IceCream", new {id = 42)})');
}
```

So that I can pass the value 42 in as the 'id' parameter in the `Details` action of the `IceCream` controller. And that works fine, but of course I don't want to hard code the value 42, rather pull the flavor id from the grid itself.  So I have tried to reference the flavorID  but can't seem to get the syntax correct:

```
onSelectRow: function(theRow){
   var grid = jQuery('#jqgFlavors');
   var flavorID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', theRow, 'FlavorID');
   $('#flavorDetails').load('@Url.Action("Details","IceCream", new {id = flavorID)})');
}
```

I'm sure you get what I'm going for here - referencing the flavorID value I extract from the grid.  But what I get is a compilation error:

**The name 'flavorID' does not exist in the current context.**

I suspect this is really simple.  How do I reference correctly that variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the second argument of the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method which allows you to pass additional parameters:

```
var flavorID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', theRow, 'FlavorID');
$('#flavorDetails').load('@Url.Action("Details", "IceCream")', { id: flavorID });
```

This might probably use the following url: `/IceCream/Details?id=123` instead of what you might want `/IceCream/Details/123` because javascript doesn't know anything about your routes but why care? It will still map correctly to the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

But if you are really anal about urls and insist on having the first type of url I've seen people doing the following:

```
var flavorID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', theRow, 'FlavorID');
var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "IceCream", new { id = "_TOREPLACE_" })';
url = url.replace('_TOREPLACE_', flavorID);
$('#flavorDetails').load(url);
```

Personally I wouldn't do it but providing it just for the record.